# Let the animation at its end state JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, css-animations

Here's my problem :

I'm developping a little animation with JS and CSS, and I would like this stop when the animation is over. Now, my animation go back to his basic state.

```js
var
 btn = document.getElementById("btn");
 anim = document.getElementById("anim");
  
// button click event
btn.addEventListener("click", ToggleAnimation, false);

// apply all webkit events
anim.addEventListener("webkitAnimationStart", AnimationListener);
anim.addEventListener("webkitAnimationIteration", AnimationListener);
anim.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", AnimationListener);

// and standard events
anim.addEventListener("animationstart", AnimationListener);
anim.addEventListener("animationiteration", AnimationListener);
anim.addEventListener("animationend", AnimationListener);

// handle animation events
function AnimationListener(e) {
 if (e.type.toLowerCase().indexOf("animationend") >= 0) {
  ToggleAnimation();
 }
}

// start/stop animation
function ToggleAnimation(e) {
 var on = (anim.className != "");
 anim.className = (on ? "" : "enable");
};
```

```css
#anim
{
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
  height:150px;
 background-color: #060;
}

#anim.enable
{
 -webkit-animation: flash 1s ease;
 animation: flash 1s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* animation */
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
 50% { margin-top:50px; }
}

@keyframes flash {
 50% { margin-top:50px; }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
  Launch animation
</button>
<p><a id="anim" href="#"></a></p>
```

Here's my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Azyme/tmb249oc/8/). I think the problem is in the function "ToggleAnimation" but I can't find what.

Thanks in advance and had a good day.

Azyme

Answer (score 0):

I think I have achieved what you are trying to - changed the animation to have a start and end state (0% and 100%) and used jquery to add the class "enable" rather than toggle it

css

```
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  0% { margin-top: 0}
  100% { margin-top:50px; }
}

@keyframes flash {
  0% { margin-top: 0}
  100% { margin-top:50px; }
}
```

jquery

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   $('#anim').addClass("enable");
})
```

hope thats helpful, made a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLLKoZ

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks a lot ! After ask to friends, they told me too it's better use JQuery method, it's more simple and you got a more light code.